# Exclude <td> from <div>

Tags: html, xslt, html-table

Is there any way to have a div around an entire table, but exclude one `<td>`?

Comment: exclude one what? at least show us the source and the desired outcome.

Comment: You need to clarify this query please. What do you mean by'but exclude one'

Comment: sorry, that must have been a typo. The question is if i can exclude one <td> in my table from the div around the whole table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but it's considered extremely poor form.  Depending on the browser, you might get the result you're looking for.  Most likely, though, you should re-think your problem and determine a solution that doesn't require fragmenting well-defined constructs.

Answer (score 0):

If your `<td>` of interest has an id or a known position, or known content, then yes, it's possible to leave it out of a transformation. When you do the transformation you just exclude it from the selection based on the thing that makes it unique.